# Anyone paying attention to tag wikis?

Tags: discussion

I had written a tag wiki for [large-cardinals] the other day, but I'm not very inclined to continue and write for other tags if there's no one to approve them.

If I have to wait until 5K rep to do it myself it's something I can deal with, but I don't see why I should do it now.

So, anyone bothers to look at these things? (which brings me back to my previous question about it - is there a possibility to have some "exemplary" tag wiki to use as reference)

Comment: I do not yet have the power to approve tag-wiki edits even though my rep is > 5K (even though http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits this says I can approve tag wiki edits). Looks like tag wikis need to be peer reviewed by those who have more than 20K points and currently there are only a couple of people more than 20K.

Comment: @siva you have the power at 5k to *vote* on them, not approve them outright.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for the clarification. Will there be any notification in my inbox when someone writes a new tag wiki?

Answer (score 13):

I thought about editing tag wikis once, when I got a notification that I could do it. I wasn't sure if it was worth the time, so I put it off. Then, strangely, the reputation required to edit them went up, and I couldn't edit them anymore. I thought that was strange at the time.

More recently, I thought about editing them again, when I noticed it says I need 5,000 to "vote" on tag wiki edits. I assumed that "vote" meant "approve", and since I don't have 5,000 yet I thought I would wait until I do so I could edit them and approve my edits. Now, based on the comments here, it seems that I can't edit the tag wikis outright without 20,000 rep.

20,000 seems like an almost absurd amount of rep to require; someone can edit other people's posts with 2,000, but they have to have double the points of the moderation tools to edit a summary of what a tag means?   Frankly, editing tag wikis with the current setup doesn't seem worth the trouble to me. I can spend time on other things that don't need someone standing over my shoulder to "approve".

I would suggest lowering the rep needed to edit tag wikis to 2,000, the same as required to edit other people's non-community-wiki posts. It takes enough time to get 2,000 to limit that to somewhat dedicated users.

***Addendum ***

I tried editing the one for "logic" now that I have 5,000 rep, and I can confirm that I can't edit it. Strangely, it said that my edit needs "peer review", but I don't think any of the four editors with over 20,000 rep is an expert in logic, so I'm not sure how they are supposed to "peer review" it. Looking for vandalism is not the same as peer review (or else my refereeing would be a lot easier) - that message ought to be changed in the interface.

Comment: +1.  My memory of the 20K rep required for editing tag wikis is that it was generated in response to a desire to give *some* additional privileges to 20K rep users.  But I agree with you that this very high bar setting seems to price this privilege out of existence.  Whatever small amount of interest I might once have had in editing tag wikis (seriously, what the heck does this even mean?  could it be much less transparent?) is long gone, and I'm plenty far away from 20K rep.

Comment: As far as I know, 5000 rep are enough to approve tag wiki edits. The only problem might be that they don't _see_ that there's something to approve!

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: that's why I waited and tried it. Although I have 5,000 rep, when I edited a tag wiki for "logic" it still told me that my post would not be visible until it was "peer reviewed". Apparently it takes 20,000. On the other hand, it's not clear from http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits whether 5,000 is enough to actually approve an edit, or just "vote to approve" it. How many votes are needed for approval? The person who approved mine has about 14,000 rep; I have no idea which privilege allowed them to approve it. The whole thing does seem very opaque.

Comment: Yes, "opaque" describes it well. Jeff writes "you have the power at 5k to vote on them, not approve them outright" in a comment here, but I don't quite know what he means ...

Answer (score 1):

I've only seen one tag wiki edit so far, but it pops up in my notifications so it's hard to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was already approved, because I don't see it in the suggested edits. Or perhaps someone rejected it?

Comment: If it has been approved then there are some bugs with the tag wiki code. It shows as though there's no tag wiki, however my writing shows in the history (but not in excerpt history).

Comment: @asaf I see the problem -- if the excerpt is blank, the page assumes the whole tag wiki is blank (even if it isn't). So you must have an excerpt at all times. I copied the first part of your entry into the excerpt and saved it.

Comment: Jeff, much obliged. Please put some sort of info about tag wiki editing - if possible.